# scroll roda e para na div que esta abaixo

Tags: html, div, rolamento, lista, html-tags

Estou desenvolvendo um website e estou com um problema. Eu quero criar o site apresentado alguns produtos, e quero que ao rolar o *scroll*, o site roda a um tamanho determinado parando na posição que eu queira.

Digamos que a página rola de 200px em 200px. Dessa forma, o site fica fixo em cada `div` de lista de produtos. Por favor, me ajudem nisto.

Comment: Existem muitas perguntas sobre essa funcionalidade e inclusive fazer scroll para o proximo elemento. Dê uma olhada por aqui e vai encontrar exemplos. A sua pergunta como está é um pouco vaga...

Comment: desculpa a minha falta de conhecimento na área acaba ficando dificílimo, e eu não estou conseguindo achar nada sobre o assunto. pode me ajudar ??

Answer (score 0):

Opa!

Nesse link, tem bastante informações sobre um tipo de função, chamada onscroll.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/onscroll

Basicamente, o que ela faz é agir perante uma movimentação especificada por você.

Por exemplo:

1. Imagine o caso onde você roda uma página em uma determinada quantidade (como por exemplo, os 500px que você especificou).
2. Assim que atingir a quantidade de pixels que você quiser, passe para essa função um link que redireciona para a determinada div, com o ID que você passar, e simule um click.

Exemplificando mais:

```js
const scrollPixelsFunction = () => (
  const link = document.getElementById('linkWhenClick');
  return link.click()
);

window.onscroll = scrollPixelsFunction;
```

```html
<div id="Scroll_pixels">
  <p>Olá</p>
</div>
```

Mas você precisa aprimorar mais a função, claro. 
É só passar pra ela a quantidade de pixels da qual você quer que sejam realizados os direcionamentos.
Pra isso, dê uma olhada no link. Ele explica sobre a definição de pixels, que foi o que você pediu.

Não sei se é uma boa prática, mas, acredito que tendo o caminho fica mais fácil pra você conseguir achar boas maneiras.

Sucesso.